# dynamic height according to width

Tags: android, android-layout

Say I have an `LinearLayout` of which the `layout_width` is set to `fill_parent`. And I want its `layout_height` to be 1.5 times `layout_width`.

I cannot hardcode it since in different device screen density differs.

I have problem implementing this, since I find no setHight or setWidth method in `View` or `ViewGroup`.

Comment: You don't know until run time how big the ViewGroup is.  So, at runtime, get your layout width and set height to width * 1.5 using layout params.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your Activity get the screen width

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
```

Then set your View height based on your width

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
myView.getLayoutParams().width = displaymetrics.widthPixels * 1.5f;
```

Comment: `fill_parent` does not mean fill screen, and in this way it can be wrong.